# PrimeFaces Datatable - draggable column fails on the first launch

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, draggable

I've got a datatable populated by items from my database. Everything works fine.
Now, I want to make the column draggable along with row draggable.

When I submit my form, my datatable is not visible. Nothing is present when I inspect the html page.

It's still the same when I refresh through F5 but I have to go to the URL and press "Enter" and then my datatable is now visible and draggable.

This is my datatable settings :

```
<p:dataTable id="datatable" var="mon" value="#{X.resultQuery}" 
                         first="#{dataTableController.first}"
                         resizableColumns="true"
                         rows="20"
                         paginator="true"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="30,40,50"
                         draggableColumns="true"
                         draggableRows="true"
                         paginatorPosition="bottom">
```

Screenshot before submit : [image]

Screenshot after submit : [image]

Screenshot after pressing "Enter" in the url section (not F5) : 
[image]
This is what I want...

How can I make this happened ? Is that a bug from Primefaces ?

Comment: Is the data table being added to the page after an ajax post?  I am guessing that this feature probably only works on a datatable that has been initialized on a full page postback of some kind.  It is impossible to tell though without seeing the whole page and what happens to initialize the dataTable initially.

Comment: I don't think so. I disabled the ajax on the commandButton. I found a way to correct that by using 

    

    `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

String viewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
        
ViewHandler handler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
        UIViewRoot root = handler.createView(context, viewId);
        root.setViewId(viewId);
        context.setViewRoot(root);`